# Can you kill Lord British in Ultima: Runes of Virtue II?

Tags: ultima-runes-of-virtue-2

There is a tradition in Ultima games to try to kill Lord British (the Ultima wiki has an article about [how to kill Lord British in each game](http://ultima.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Lord_British)). However, it's missing an entry for *[Ultima: Runes of Virtue II](http://ultima.wikia.com/wiki/Ultima:_Runes_of_Virtue_II)*, a console game for the GameBoy and Super Nintendo.

Is it possible in either version to kill Lord British?